# WPF/Xaml ContextMenu ItemContainerStyle behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The DataContext for my window is an IDictionary>.

Can anyone explain to me why this works fine:

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle">
    <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding Ticker}"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ContextMenuStyle">
    <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding Key}"/>
    <Setter Property="MenuItem.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Value}"/>
    <Setter Property="MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}"/>
</Style>
<ContextMenu ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContextMenuStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Quotes}" />
```

But this does not:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}" x:Key="ContextMenuStyle">
    <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding Key}"/>
    <Setter Property="MenuItem.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Value}"/>
    <Setter Property="MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Ticker}"/>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<ContextMenu ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContextMenuStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Quotes}" />
```

EDIT: if i remove T'argetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}"', it works fine.  i don't clearly understand why however.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the value of the `TargetType` from `ContextMenu` to `MenuItem`. The `ItemContainerStyle` property of the `ContextMenu` sets the style to the container element of your `ContextMenu`, in this case a `MenuItem`. However you set the target type of the style to `ContextMenu` so it cannot work. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) for more details.